# How to make sure nproc values are taking effect for all the users?

Tags: centos, ulimit

In the */etc/security/limit.conf* file I have added the following values:

```
user1      -     nproc     unlimited 
user2      -     nproc     unlimited
```

Both *user1* and *user2* have **sudo** privileges and I used *user1* to make this change. I then logged out of the server and logged back in.

When I check as user1, the ulimit -u command goves me output 'Unlimited'.
**However, when I check as user2, the ulimit -u command gives me value of 10000.**

Where can this value be coming from?

Answer (score 0):

It seems a cluster management process (ambari) was modifying the values for that particular user.